# Map Keyboard Combination to Mouse Right Click - C#

Tags: c#

I am creating a program which will automate some office works. Is some cases I must copy students' numbers to clipboard and paste them some where else.

I need to map "Ctrl+V" (paste) to mouse Right click while running my App So When I right click some where, instead of normal mouse right click, it do pasting.

How Can I make such thing via C#?

Comment: I have just started it, but after some searching so many people decided to use AutoHotKey or other Third party apps using this combining with my c# app which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have just checked the code to copy in my companys application and it is massive, you should really consider using some 3rd party tool. If you are going to write it, it will take a while. Best of luck.

Comment: @Carl it is not possible to mail it please?